# How to chunk results from a custom query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

I have a custom query that grabs data from the old system and maps it to models in the new system. The query looks like this:

`$companies = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...");`

And since it's a lot of data, I'd like to use Eloquent's chunk feature (just sample code copied from their docs):

```
User::chunk(200, function($users)
{
    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
        //
    }
});
```

How do I implement this?

---

Edit: My code now looks like this, which results in no response:

```
DB::connection('legacy')->select("SELECT * FROM companies")->chunk(200, function($companies) {
    foreach ($companies as $company) {
        // dd($company);
        $entity       = Entity::firstOrNew(['external_id' => $company->companyKey]);
        $entity->name = $company->companyName;
        $entity->save();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try doing this: `var_dump($companies);exit;` inside the chuck function to see if it's returning anything. How many rows are there in the `companies` table?

Comment: Hm, still nothing. There are thousands of records, but I'm limiting the results to just 10 for now. Additionally, I do get results back when I use the non-chunked approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$max = 100;
$total = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->count();
$pages = ceil($total / $max);
for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
    $offset = (($i - 1)  * $max);
    $start = ($offset == 0 ? 0 : ($offset + 1));
    $legacy = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->skip($start)->take($max)->get();
    /* Do stuff. */
}
```

Basically duplicates what Laravel's Paginator does without the extra overhead.

Comment: Umm, doesn't $total = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->count(); fetch all the objects while counting them? Kind of defeats the purpose :(

Comment: The 'extra overhead' is that you do many DB requests instead of only one

Comment: @MaciejSwic For you and future people look at this, I change count() line to `DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) as rows')[0]->rows` to return it.

Answer (score 14):

The `chunk` feature is only available for Eloquent models and QueryBuilder requests, e.g.

```
DB::table('tbl')->where('num', '>', 3)->chunk(500, function($rows) {
    // process $rows
});
```

But it won't work for `DB::select('...')` request. 
You need to either use a QueryBuilder request, or use an underlying PDO object to query the database, e.g:

```
$pdo = DB::getPdo();
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ....");
$sth->execute();
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** March 2018 a new function was added to the query builder class. It's possible to achieve the same now using `fromSub`:

```
$subQuery = DB::table('users')->where(...);

DB::query()->fromSub($subQuery, 'alias')->orderBy('alias.id')->chunk(200, function ($chunk) {
    // Do something
});
```

And to use a different connection start with `DB::connection('legacy')->query()`

---

**Old answer:** Found this question by accident, but a little trick that might come handy in some cases.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ... JOIN ... UNION ... WHATEVER ... GROUP BY';

// This is the important part:
$query = '(' . $query . ') somealias';

DB::connection('legacy')->table(DB::raw($query))->chunk(1000, function($rows){
    // Do something
});
```

The query laravel executes then goes like this:

```
select * from (...) somealias LIMIT ... OFFSET ...
```

This should work at least in Laravel 5.1. But I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work in 4+.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of answers on this page do a lookup of all records in order to workout how many 'pages' there are. This can be slow and is not needed as we are not paginating we are chunking. We only need to know the total number of pages when we are paginating to show the user.

So an alternative to getting a count of all records at the start is to do the following:

```
    $recordsRemaining = true;
    $lookupsCompleted = 0;
    $chunkSize = 200;

    while($recordsRemaining){
       $companies = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->skip($chunkSize*$lookupsCompleted)->take($chunkSize)->get();

       if($legacy->count() < $chunkSize){
          $recordsRemaining = false;
       }
       foreach($companies as $company){
          //Do something
       }

       $lookupsCompleted++;
    }
```

This does exactly the same as the accepted answer but is more efficient.

Comment: Where does `$legacy->count()` come from? Do you mean `$companies->count()` on the line where you are checking if the amount of records remaining is less than chunk size?

Answer (score 4):

deyes's answer has a bug.

AS-IS

if 'legacy' table has 'id' column and there's 1,2,3,4,5 ... 100 numbered data.

```
<?php

$max = 10;
$total = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->count();
$pages = ceil($total / $max);
for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
    $offset = (($i - 1)  * $max);
    $start = ($offset == 0 ? 0 : ($offset + 1));
    $legacy = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->skip($start)->take($max)->get();
    /* Do stuff. */

    $legacyIds = $legacy->lists("id");
    echo "i = " . $i . ": \n";
    print_r($legacyIds);
}

//Result
i = 1: 
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
i = 2: 
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 15
    [4] => 16
    [5] => 17
    [6] => 18
    [7] => 19
    [8] => 20
    [9] => 21
) ...
```

TO-DO

```
$max = 10;
$total = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->count();
$pages = ceil($total / $max);
for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
    $offset = (($i - 1)  * $max);
    $legacy = DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->skip($offset)->take($max)->get();
    /* Do stuff. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers worked for me. I created my own function based on @deyes answer.

```
private static function chunk($query, $max, $function) {
    $counter = preg_replace('/SELECT (.*?) FROM/', 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM', $query);
    $total = DB::connection('legacy')->select($counter)[0];
    $total = (array)$total;
    $total = $total['COUNT(*)'];

    $pages = ceil($total / $max);

    for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
        $offset = (($i - 1)  * $max);
        $start = ($offset == 0 ? 0 : ($offset + 1));
        $items = DB::connection('legacy')->select($query . ' LIMIT ' . $offset . ', ' . $max);

        $function($items);

        unset($items);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
YourClass::chunk('SELECT * FROM tablename', 50, function($items) {
    //Work with $items.
});
```

Please note that this a simple quick fix and your query probably has to be fairly simple as I'm using search-replace to build a count query and I'm just tacking on LIMIT X, Y to the end of the query but it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can use `chunk` on a query builder. E.g.

```
DB::connection('legacy')->select("...")->chunk(200, function($companies){
    //do something with $companies
});
```

Comment: I attempted this approach but unfortunately I get no output now.

Comment: I tried this as well. Nothing from inside the function($companies) gets returned.

Answer (score -2):

Try using the **orderBy** clause:

```
DB::table('tbl')->where('num', '>', 3)->orderBy('id')->chunk(500, function($rows) {
    // process $rows
});
```