# How to chunk results from a custom query with Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Following up on this Question: [How to chunk results from a custom query in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048104/how-to-chunk-results-from-a-custom-query-in-laravel)

I try

```
DB::connection('mgnt')->select($query)->chunk(200, function($orders) {
    foreach ($orders as $order) { 

    //a bunch of code...

    }
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in MigrationController.php line 98:
 Call to a member function chunk() on array
```

Is chunking possible without having an appropriate Eloquent ORM Model?
I try to chunk because I get a blank page (can't find any errrors in any log) if the query returns too many results.

I think right now it max 50.000 results that I can query at once. Is that maybe due to some restriction or limitation in Laravel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since the query will just return an array of objects you can simply use PHP's [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$result = DB::connection('mgnt')->select($query);
foreach(array_chunk($result, 200) as $orders){
    foreach($orders as $order){
        // a bunch of code...
    }
}
```

---

Here's what `chunk()` on an eloquent model does:

```
$results = $this->forPage($page = 1, $count)->get();

while (count($results) > 0)
{
    // On each chunk result set, we will pass them to the callback and then let the
    // developer take care of everything within the callback, which allows us to
    // keep the memory low for spinning through large result sets for working.
    call_user_func($callback, $results);

    $page++;

    $results = $this->forPage($page, $count)->get();
}
```

You could try to do something similar (although I think it should be possible to run your query all at once, but I can't help you with that...)

1. Add a limit to your SQL query `LIMIT 200`
2. Increase the offset with every query you run. First 0, second 1 * 200, third 2 * 200
3. Do that until the result is returned empty (e.g. with a while loop like above)

Comment: nice idea, but the problem seems to be the first line as the result is too big to process, saved or received, i was hoping the chunk function of laravel would break apart the request.

Comment: Ah I see. Then why not use an Eloquent model? I don't know what's limiting the number of results. It may be the PHP execution time or some other setting on the webserver or database server...

Comment: it's a complex ETL query with subqueries, variables, calculations, around 60 lines of SQL. I tested it with different MySQL clients and the results takes 17 seconds and returns 250k rows.

Comment: I've updated my answer. But I really think it should actually be possible to run it all at once...